# PHP: Pass variables to file_get_contents()

Tags: php

Is there a way to make this possible?

```
// file.php
echo $foo;
```

then in

```
// test.php
$foo = 'bar';
echo file_get_contents('file.php');
```

The output of test.php should be "bar".

Comment: maybe with `include('file.php');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

```
$foo = 'bar';
require_once('./file.php');
```

And in file.php it's just:

```
echo $foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
// file.php
function outputFoo($foo) {
  echo $foo;
}


// test.php
$foo = 'bar';
include 'file.php';
outputFoo($foo);
```

But really, all that is actually needed in your case is:

```
// file.php
echo $foo;

// test.php
$foo = 'bar';
include 'file.php';
```

As file.php will have access to your `$foo`-variable as well. (This only works when file.php and test.php is within the same domain).

Answer (score 0):

```
ob_start();
include 'file.php';
echo ob_get_clean();
```

But really, this seems like a rather nonsensical thing to do. If you just want `file.php` evaluated and have it output its contents, simply `include` the file.

Comment: Yes, using the ob-function seems nonsensical in this case. That should be avoided as it's not required to provide the expected output.